# CultureManager issue

Tags: c#, localization, .net-4.5

I have a bug I don't understand.

While the following works fine:

```
Resources.Classes.AFieldFormula.DirectFieldFormula
```

this one throws an exception:

```
new ResourceManager(typeof(Resources.Classes.AFieldFormula)).GetString("DirectFieldFormula");
```

`Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure \"Resources.Classes.AFieldFormula.resources\" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly \"MygLogWeb\" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.`

How comes?

Resource designer.cs file:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.18408
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Resources.Classes {
    using System;


    /// <summary>
    ///   A strongly-typed resource class, for looking up localized strings, etc.
    /// </summary>
    // This class was auto-generated by the StronglyTypedResourceBuilder
    // class via a tool like ResGen or Visual Studio.
    // To add or remove a member, edit your .ResX file then rerun ResGen
    // with the /str option, or rebuild your VS project.
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "4.0.0.0")]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
    public class AFieldFormula {

        private static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager resourceMan;

        private static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo resourceCulture;

        [global::System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1811:AvoidUncalledPrivateCode")]
        internal AFieldFormula() {
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   Returns the cached ResourceManager instance used by this class.
        /// </summary>
        [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        public static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
            get {
                if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null)) {
                    global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("MygLogWeb.Classes.AFieldFormula", typeof(AFieldFormula).Assembly);
                    resourceMan = temp;
                }
                return resourceMan;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   Overrides the current thread's CurrentUICulture property for all
        ///   resource lookups using this strongly typed resource class.
        /// </summary>
        [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        public static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo Culture {
            get {
                return resourceCulture;
            }
            set {
                resourceCulture = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   Looks up a localized string similar to Direct field.
        /// </summary>
        public static string DirectFieldFormula {
            get {
                return ResourceManager.GetString("DirectFieldFormula", resourceCulture);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My resources files are located in a \Classes folder of my solution which default namespace is MygLogWeb.

But I used the resx property windows to set the "Custom Tool Namespace" as Resources.Classes.

IS that wrong? Do I really have to make my folders reflects the namespaces?

Comment: There's a clear mismatch between "Resources.Classes.AFieldFormula" as used by your code and "MygLogWeb.Classes.AFieldFormula" as used by the resource designer.  With high odds that the resource designer got that right.  Otherwise a very good reason to rely on the resource designer, namespace names for resources are rather a big headache.  You can always tell which one was used by running ildasm.exe on the assembly, look at the manifest and locate the .mresource directive.

Comment: @HansPassant My resources files are located in a \Classes folder of my solution which default namespace is MygLogWeb. But I used the resx property windows to set the "Custom Tool Namespace" as Resources.Classes. IS that wrong? Do I really have to manage my folders exactly the same as namespaces?

Answer (score 0):

Hans Passant explained why it didn"t work.

So I looked deeper into how .Net handled it, and it does it using Reflection instead of ResourceManager.

So, if you want to get Resources from a Type it might be the only compile safe way to do so.

Here's how I've done it for my custom attribute:

```
public class FriendlyNameAttribute : Attribute
{
    private delegate string dGetString();

    private dGetString dValue;

    public string ResourceName
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public Type ResourceType
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    private void CheckValue()
    {
        this.dValue = () => this.ResourceName;

        if (this.ResourceType == null || !this.ResourceType.IsVisible ||  this.ResourceName == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var property = this.ResourceType.GetProperty(this.ResourceName);

        if (property == null || property.PropertyType != typeof(string))
        {
            return;
        }

        this.dValue = () => (string)property.GetValue(null, null);
    }

    public FriendlyNameAttribute(string resourceName, Type resourceType = null)
    {
        this.ResourceName = resourceName;
        this.ResourceType = resourceType;
        this.CheckValue();
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dValue();
        }
    }
}
```